# Write a Class with varying properties

Tags: vba, excel

I have to write VBA code that will need a class called `Class_Name`.

Each Object of that class will be initially getting properties form spreadsheet, but the catch is the fields in those properties will change overtime and I need my `Class_Name` to handle those fields without me changing the code.

What are the best practices to accomplish that?

I am thinking about putting all found fields into an array that will be dynamic, but I have a feeling that there is an design pattern for this, or some other sort of commonly used solution that I am unavare of.

Example:

Worksheet1

field1, filed2

Worksheet2

field1 ....  filed100